# While loop does not work in C++ when I have return inside it

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, return, do-while

I'm new to C++ and working on the following code, which rotates a given 2D matrix. My code works fine for one rotation. Then I add a while loop to my code to make it more general, I noticed that the while code does not go to more iteration no matter what. I tried to bring the `return MatrixRotateOutPut` out of the while but then it was unknown.

I also tried to add `return 0` after while loop but it gives me another error. I also checked these two links ([Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038584/while-loop-wont-loop-c), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090734/c-do-while-loop-and-calling-functions)), but they were not really helpful for me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int MatrixPrint2D(vector<vector<int>> Input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Input[0].size(); j++) {
            printf("%d ", Input[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


vector<vector<int>> MatrixRotate(vector<vector<int>> Input, int Irritation) {

    while (Irritation > 0) {
        cout << Irritation << "\n" << endl;

        vector<vector<int>> MatrixRotateOutPut(Input[0].size(), vector<int>(Input.size(), 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < Input.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Input[0].size(); j++) {

                MatrixRotateOutPut[j][Input.size() - 1 - i] = Input[i][j];

            }
        }
        vector<vector<int>> Input(MatrixRotateOutPut.size(), vector<int>(MatrixRotateOutPut[0].size(), 1));
        Input = MatrixRotateOutPut;

        MatrixPrint2D(MatrixRotateOutPut);
        printf("\n");

        Irritation--;
        return MatrixRotateOutPut;

    }
}


int main() {
    
    //Define a matrix for testing:
    vector<vector<int>> Matrix2(4, vector<int>(5, 1));
    int R = 2;
    int C = 4;
    vector<vector<int>> MatrixInput(R, vector<int>(C, 1));;

    for (int i = 0; i < MatrixInput.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MatrixInput[0].size(); j++) {
            int temp;
            temp = i ^ (2 * j);

            MatrixInput[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }

    cout << "MatrixInput:" << endl;
    MatrixPrint2D(MatrixInput);
    printf("\n");

    vector<vector<int>> OutPut2 = MatrixRotate(MatrixInput, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obviously when you return from inside the loop, you are no longer inside the loop. Did you mean to return *after* the loop?

Comment: @harold The only way that I can get a output is when I put it inside the loop, I dont even know how to put the return after the loop and make it works

Comment: Your matrix should be defined outside the loop. Then you can return outside the loop.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am sorry for the bad questions, I am just a beginner and I did not know that is too obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following:

- Move the return outside of the loop
- Move the declaration of the returned variable outside of the loop.

So:

```
vector<vector<int>> MatrixRotate(vector<vector<int>> Input, int Irritation) {
    vector<vector<int>> MatrixRotateOutPut;
    while (Irritation > 0) {
        cout << Irritation << "\n" << endl;

        MatrixRotateOutPut = vector<vector<int>>(Input[0].size(), vector<int>(Input.size(), 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < Input.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Input[0].size(); j++) {

                MatrixRotateOutPut[j][Input.size() - 1 - i] = Input[i][j];

            }
        }
        vector<vector<int>> Input(MatrixRotateOutPut.size(), vector<int>(MatrixRotateOutPut[0].size(), 1));
        Input = MatrixRotateOutPut;

        MatrixPrint2D(MatrixRotateOutPut);
        printf("\n");

        Irritation--;
    }
    return MatrixRotateOutPut;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much